# Drive-SDK Python code not GETting drive files by selected title words

Tags: python, get, google-drive-api

I need to pass a query to a function. It should be really simple! here is the code:

```
def get_file_ID(q):
  dump = drive_service.files().list(q=q, fields = 'items(mimeType,id,title,downloadUrl)').execute()
  fileItems = dump['items']
  for item in fileItems:
    try:
        if item['mimeType'] == "application/octet-stream":
          return item['id']
    except KeyError:
        print "No item of the required type, or item has been deleted"
        return None

def lets_go_get(file_Id):
  f = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_Id).execute()
  resp, content = drive_service._http.request(f.get('id'))
  if resp.status == 200:
      #print 'Status: %s' % resp
      return content
  else:
      print 'An error occurred: %s' % resp
      return None

text = raw_input('Enter title search text: ')
query = "title contains '" + text +"'"
selectedFile = "'" + get_file_ID(query) +"'"

print lets_go_get(selectedFile)
```

I get the following error:

```
   HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/%270BxDfMkL6x0wjMS03Nz.....Tk%27?alt=json returned "File not found: '0BxDfMkL6x0wjMS03.....MTU5NjQ0ZjdhOTk'">
```

But when i substitute the last call to 'lets_go_get' with the DIRECT fileID like this:

```
print lets_go_get('0BxDfMkL6x0wjMS03.....MTU5NjQ0ZjdhOTk')
```

then it works.

I can't see any difference between the two.  can anyone explain what I'm missing???

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `downloadUrl` to download the contents:

```
f = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_Id).execute()
resp, content = drive_service._http.request(f.get('downloadUrl'))
```

Docs have a working sample on the "Python" tab: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks Burcu.  I did see that working sample but it explained for a _drive file instance_ not for a _file Id_.  Do you understand (can you explain) the difference between these two.  Your solution is 80 times clearer than the sample. Thank you

Comment: There are no differences in fact, the sample only wraps the same code in another function. I agree that it looks more bulky, we should improve the samples. Thanks.

Comment: _there are no differences in fact_ ...that is **excellent** to know!